# Centrar Encabezados de kartik GridView yii2

Tags: yii2

Buenas tardes como podría centrar los encabezados de columna de un gridview hecho con el widget kartik

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) puedes centrar el encabezado agregando la clase [`text-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment) o bien usando propiedad CSS [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) con el valor `center`.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
[
  'attribute' => 'nombre',
  'headerOptions' => [
    'class' => 'text-center',
    'style' => 'text-align: center;',
  ],
],
```